# Change cell button image on click

Tags: iphone

i am adding button as subview, when user hit on the button, i want to change the button image of that cell which 1 is click.....?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand your question...but u can try save IndexPath.row in your button's tag, and then in the (IBAction) cast (id) sender to UIButton * and use that tag...
edit: Wait, what do u mean by "cell"? is it UITableVIew or just button?:S

Comment: are u adding it in CellForRowAtIndexPath?  
u read its image from an Array?  
u can save row number in the "tag" of the UIButton and in the IBAction and change the image in the array...  
then u should reloadTable.